# Proof of Residue Limit Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

We have the following theorem in Stein's Complex Analysis, p. 76:

If $f$ has a pole of order $n$ at $z_0$, then: $$ res_{z_0}f = \text{lim}_{z\rightarrow z_0}{1 \over (n-1)!}\bigg({d \over dz}\bigg)^{n-1}(z-z_0)^nf(z).$$

This is derived from the formula $$ (1) \qquad (z-z_0)^nf(z) = a_{-n}+a_{-n+1}(z-z_0) + ... + a_{-1}(z-z_0)^{n-1} + G(z)(z-z_0)^n,$$

where $$f(z) = a_{-n}(z-z_0)^{-n} +a_{-n+1}(z-z_0)^{-n+1} + ... + a_{-1}(z-z_0)^{-1} + G(z).$$ My question is, why do we not have to consider the value $G(z)$? Shouldn't the residue formula actually look like this:

$$res_{z_0}f = \text{lim}_{z\rightarrow z_0}{1 \over (n-1)!}\bigg({d \over dz}\bigg)^{n-1}(z-z_0)^n[f(z)-G(z)].$$

That is, if we differentiate $(1)$ $n-1$ times, shouldn't we get:

$${1 \over (n-1)!}(z-z_0)f(z) = a_{-1} + {1 \over (n-1)!}(z-z_0)G(z).$$ As $z_0 \rightarrow z$, the proof assumes the last summand on the right-hand side goes to zero, I just don't understand why. Thanks!

Comment: $G(z)$ is the Taylor part of the Laurent Series for $f$, so $(z-z{_{0}})^{n}G(z)$ and its derivatives up to and including the $(n-1)$th is zero as $z\rightarrow z_{0}$